# How to setup Mongo Replica on AWS?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, mongodb-query, nosql

I am working on MongoDB and the requirement is to install MongoDB replication on AWS cloud.
Numerous Tutorial and blogs view but no one mention

1.how to set up Ip(which IP used pubic/private)

2.How to set firewall for primary, secondary and arbitrary

3.rs.add(hostname);// hostname is private Ip or Public

4.If one of my instance at a different zone then how to setup

5.How to use SSL in replica.

Please share information related to this If anyone knows about this.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation/tutorials describe the required operations but they aren't built for every person's individual use case (obviously, they can't cover different use cases all at the same time).

> 1.how to set up Ip(which IP used pubic/private)

Either one is possible depending on how you want to access the database.

> 2.How to set firewall for primary, secondary and arbitrary

Depends on who you want to have access to the database.

> 3.rs.add(hostname);// hostname is private Ip or Public

Same as 1.

> 4.If one of my instance at a different zone then how to setup

MongoDB doesn't care where the nodes are.

> 5.How to use SSL in replica.

This is covered by MongoDB documentation.

Comment: Thanks,  My requirement is to set up Mongo on AWS, and the problem I faced are: 1. how to use public Ip for communication with MongoDB, 2. if the zone is different then how to set bindIP  3. after setup how to enable SSL. If you have any idea, please share

Comment: If you are looking for someone to delegate your task to,  there are developers out there who would be happy to do that for appropriate compensation. On this site you need to follow the Q&A format which means asking specific questions.

Comment: Therefore I raised the questions. If you know then give the solution otherwise don't consider it as a non -question.